# Calculate the distance of two devices that are connected into the same local network base on the given LAT and LONG

Tags: java, android, gps

Does anyone already achieve this kind of task before?

I've been searching for an hour and I didn't find anything that suit to my requirement except the thing called `"Triangulate"`.

I'm having a hard time, I want to implement this into two devices running an Android Operating System but I really can't push myself anymore.

> The process will required a Server(ServerSocket) and Client(Socket),
>   both of them are Connected into the same Local Network,  the Server
>   will listen for incoming clients, and once they're become connected,
>   the Client will fetch the current LAT and LONG using the GPS and send
>   it to Server, the Server now will calculate the distance of the Client
>   from the Server itself and display it into graphical
>   interface(Basically the interface is just showing two icon and their
>   distance).

I've already done the `ServerSocket`, `Socket` and the `GPS` thing, the only task I'm stock with is on how can I calculate the distance of the given LAT and LONG.

Comment: It's not LANG, it's LONG as in longitude. In any case, the problem seems easy enough. Two devices, both with their own gps coordinates. Just geocode them and measure the distance with a mapping api like Google Maps. Unless I'm missing something, triangulation shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - I Updated, I haven't found that thing called `Geocode`, I'm not sure about you're idea but if possible I don't want to use the Google Map API to show the location of the two inside the map, I just want a two icon and their distance to each other. Thank you anyway, I'm gonna take a look about the `Geocode`.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - It does make sense, both the device has a GPS, what about getting the Server current LAT and LONG using the GPS and compare into the Client? Now the problem is how can I show the distance of two icons graphically.

Comment: Geocoding is probably overkill. Follow Davis Herring's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing distances from geographic coordinates is a [well-studied](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) problem, of course.  Make sure to pick a version of the formula that is accurate for small distances.